# Complete email client is possible or not in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, email, email-client

I have to make an application of email client. is it possible to make an application that can manage different email addresses. In application we have to provide inbox for different id. I don't know how I'll connect to all servers. and how it will work? can anybody guide me?

This is really new for me thats why please don't mind if my question is silly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There used to be an app, remail, then open sourced by google: http://code.google.com/p/remail-iphone/
Also on the OneMail app website you'll find a list with the frameworks they're using: http://codev.co.uk/products/onemail/notice

Answer (score 0):

I guess that it is possible, since it is an "stand alone" app and not an improvement to the native app.